# Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler hamburger is button not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

On mobile view, when I click the nabar-toggler button it opens the menu, but when I click it again it doesn't close the menu. I have no idea what the issue could be? I checked all the cdn links, the compiled css and everything else is working fine in the app except for this. Need help ya'll! Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="full-height">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Brandon Matthews</title>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
  <link href="./public/assets/css/compiled1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--My CSS-->
  <link href="./public/assets/css/index.css">


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Main navigation -->
  <header>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Matthews Development</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home
                                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about" data-offset="90">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio" data-offset="90">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact" data-offset="90">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Social Icon -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav nav-flex-icons">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/brandon-matthews-b14165153/">
                <i class="fa fa-linkedin white-text"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/BrandonM25">
                <i class="fa fa-github white-text"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook white-text"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar -->
```

Comment: Do you mean the toggler button doesn't close it again, or clicking on the links doesn't close it?

Comment: clicking on the toggler button and the links does not close it.

Answer (score 9):

I think you haven't imported all the necessary bootstrap js files mentioned here (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

I created a jdfiddle of your code (https://jsfiddle.net/8vc79boj/8/) and added bootstrap 4 javascript files and it worked for me.

These are the scripts I have added

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks just pasted it to my code and now it works! Duh!