# Hamburger toggle button not working is Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, togglebutton

I made header using HTML CSS and Bootstrap on localhost and on localhost the toggle button is working fine but when i push this code on wordpress the toggle button stops working. I took every step possible to make it work. I have tried CDNs in many orders, also putted jquery CDN before the bootstrap CDN but nothing works. I also made all necessary changes which is required like converting data-target to data-bs-target but nothing happens. I also followed this post [Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler hamburger is button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635024/bootstrap-4-navbar-toggler-hamburger-is-button-not-working) but is not working for me. Here is the code....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Header</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    li {
      color: rgb(108, 108, 189);
    }
    
    .color {
      color: #EE0000;
    }
    
    .bg-color {
      background-color: #ed5353;
    }
    
    .navbar .navbar-brand img {
      background-color: #212529;
    }
    
    #login:hover {
      background-color: #EE0000;
    }
    
    a.nav-item:hover {
      background-color: #EE0000;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">


    <a class="navbar-brand text-light mx-5" href="#"><img src="https://ablore.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/logo.png" style="width: 150px; background-color: #212529;" alt=""></a>



    <span class="justify-content-center text-light d-inline d-md-inline d-lg-none" style="margin: auto;"><i
            class="fa-solid fa-globe fs-4"></i>
          English
    
          <button class="btn btn-dark mx-4 justify-content-center from-center d-inline d-md-inline d-lg-none" id="login"
            type="submit">Login</button></span>


    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active text-light" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>


        <div class="dropdown show">
          <a class=" dropdown-toggle nav-item nav-link text-light" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
            Services
        </a>

        </div>

      </div>















      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-light from-center" href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link text-light" href="#">Insights</a>

      <div class="container d-flex" style="justify-content: end;">
        <span class=" text-light d-none d-md-none d-lg-inline"><i class="fa-solid fa-globe fs-5"></i>
              English
    
              <button class="btn btn-dark mx-4  d-none d-md-none d-lg-inline" id="login" type="submit">Login</button></span>
      </div>
    </div>


  </nav>




  <div class="collapse position-absolute" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> BRANDING
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Logo Design</li>
              <li>Website Design</li>
              <li>E-commerce Graphics</li>
              <li>Social Media Graphics</li>
              <li>Ads Graphics</li>
              <li>Video Ads</li>
              <li>Company Profile Design</li>
              <li>Content Writing</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>SaaS Development</li>
              <li>Web Portal Development</li>
              <li>E-commerce Development</li>
              <li>Mobile Application Development</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"> <span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> SALES
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Sales Process Development</li>
              <li>Automated Sales Process</li>
              <li>Sales Team</li>
              <li>Tele Caller</li>
              <li>Customer Support Team</li>
              <li>Sales Software</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> MARKETING
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Social Media Management</li>
              <li>Paid Media Management</li>
              <li>Email Marketing</li>
              <li>Content Marketing</li>
              <li>Search Engine Optimization</li>
              <li>Bulk SMS Marketing</li>
              <li>Bulk WhatsApp Marketing</li>
              <li>Automated Calls</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> CLOUDS
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>Development Servers</li>
              <li>Shared CPU</li>
              <li>Dedicated CPU</li>
              <li>Intel Servers</li>
              <li>AMD Servers</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> IT INFRASTRUCTURE
                  <hr>
                </span>
            <ul>
              <li>DevOps Engineer</li>
              <li>IT Support</li>
              <li>Product Development</li>
              <li>Project Infrastructure</li>
              <li>Product Architecture</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> ERP SOFTWARE
                  <hr>
                </span></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> CRM SOFTWARE
                  <hr>
                </span></div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> REMOTE SOFTWARE
                  <hr>
                </span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of invalid HTML and incorrect Bootstrap Navbar attributes, elements.

1. You mixed `button` with in `span` for **English** and **Login** menu. This is invalid HTML.
2. You use Bootstrap 4 JS only in your code above. You don't have any CSS.
3. You use Bootstrap 4 assets while your code is **Bootstrap 5**.
4. Because of #3, your code is incorrect attributes. For example, in Bootstrap 4 navbar use [`data-toggle="collapse"`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) while in Bootstrap 5 use [`data-bs-toggle="collapse"`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) and more.

So, which version do you really want to use?

It is not possible that this will work on your localhost while on WordPress is broken. They both should be broken because you use incorrect version of CSS and JS or HTML attributes including classes.

### Quick fix

For quick fix, I use the correct Bootstrap CSS & JS version (v.5) and it's just working fine.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  color: rgb(108, 108, 189);
}

.color {
  color: #EE0000;
}

.bg-color {
  background-color: #ed5353;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand img {
  background-color: #212529;
}



#login:hover {
  background-color: #EE0000;
}

a.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #EE0000;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">


  <a class="navbar-brand text-light mx-5" href="#"><img src="https://ablore.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/logo.png" style="width: 150px; background-color: #212529;" alt=""></a>



  <span class="justify-content-center text-light d-inline d-md-inline d-lg-none" style="margin: auto;"><i class="fa-solid fa-globe fs-4"></i> English</span>

  <button class="btn btn-dark mx-4 justify-content-center from-center d-inline d-md-inline d-lg-none" id="login" type="submit">Login</button>


  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active text-light" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>


      <div class="dropdown show">
        <a class=" dropdown-toggle nav-item nav-link text-light" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#collapseExample" data-bs-toggle="collapse">
          Services
        </a>

      </div>

    </div>


    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-light from-center" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link text-light" href="#">Insights</a>

    <div class="container d-flex" style="justify-content: end;">
      <span class=" text-light d-none d-md-none d-lg-inline"><i class="fa-solid fa-globe fs-5"></i>
        English

        <button class="btn btn-dark mx-4  d-none d-md-none d-lg-inline" id="login" type="submit">Login</button></span>
    </div>
  </div>


</nav>




<div class="collapse position-absolute" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> BRANDING
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>Logo Design</li>
            <li>Website Design</li>
            <li>E-commerce Graphics</li>
            <li>Social Media Graphics</li>
            <li>Ads Graphics</li>
            <li>Video Ads</li>
            <li>Company Profile Design</li>
            <li>Content Writing</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> PRODUCT DEVELOPMENT
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>SaaS Development</li>
            <li>Web Portal Development</li>
            <li>E-commerce Development</li>
            <li>Mobile Application Development</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"> <span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> SALES
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>Sales Process Development</li>
            <li>Automated Sales Process</li>
            <li>Sales Team</li>
            <li>Tele Caller</li>
            <li>Customer Support Team</li>
            <li>Sales Software</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> MARKETING
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>Social Media Management</li>
            <li>Paid Media Management</li>
            <li>Email Marketing</li>
            <li>Content Marketing</li>
            <li>Search Engine Optimization</li>
            <li>Bulk SMS Marketing</li>
            <li>Bulk WhatsApp Marketing</li>
            <li>Automated Calls</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> CLOUDS
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>Development Servers</li>
            <li>Shared CPU</li>
            <li>Dedicated CPU</li>
            <li>Intel Servers</li>
            <li>AMD Servers</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> IT INFRASTRUCTURE
            <hr>
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li>DevOps Engineer</li>
            <li>IT Support</li>
            <li>Product Development</li>
            <li>Project Infrastructure</li>
            <li>Product Architecture</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> ERP SOFTWARE
            <hr>
          </span></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> CRM SOFTWARE
            <hr>
          </span></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><span class="fs-5 fw-bold"> REMOTE SOFTWARE
            <hr>
          </span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See it in action on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsnjp6Lh/).

When you are coding, always note that which version you are using and don't just mixed them nor copy and paste from anywhere.
Stay focus, stick only to the version you use.

Comment: First of all thanks for the well defined answer @vee. I pushed this code which you provided on to the wordpress but that also doesn't but this header is working fine when i preview it on wordpress and when i open the website url it again stops working. You can also check the same from here https://ablore.xyz/ab

Comment: Can't detect CSS, JS correctly. It is because LiteSpeed cache that bundled the files. Disable cache while checking your code if everything is working fine then re-enable again. If re-enabled cache and the problem still exists, that is the cache problem.

Comment: disabling the cache can't do the job. Or is it because of the other pages which are written in the similar manner ?

Comment: @WaqarAnsari Disable the cache plugin (LiteSpeed), then maybe create new empty page for testing. Check again that you are using correct Bootstrap CSS & JS version. That is all.

Comment: @WaqarAnsari From view source of your web site, your HTML is super messed! There are many open doctype (`<!doctype HTML>`). If you validate your HTML with https://validator.w3.org/ there are a lot of errors.